# web3j is not generating struct inside my solidity contract

Tags: solidity, web3j, java

I have a struct `Question` in my smart contract. After generating the java wrapper class of my smart contract using **web3j**, Inside the wrapper class Question is not recognized, looks like web3j is not generating struct code in the wrapper class.

**In short, web3j does generate a java wrapper class but forgets to handle the struct.**

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.16;


contract Quiz{

struct Question{
    string statement;
     string[4] options;
    uint correctIndex;
}

    Question[] questions;


    constructor() payable{
        addQuestions();
    }


    function addQuestions()public payable{
         questions.push(Question("Who is the CEO of Pakistan?", ["Shehbaz Sharif","Gen. Bajwa","Imran Khan","Zardari"], 1));
         questions.push(Question("Capital of Pakistan?", ["Lahore","Quetta","Karachi","Islamabad"], 3));
         questions.push(Question("When android acquried firebase offically?", ["2011","2014","2013","2015"], 1));
         questions.push(Question("Advantages of decentralized App?", ["Speed, efficiency and accuracy","Trust and transparency","Savings","All of these"], 3));
         questions.push(Question("What are the application of smart contracts?", ["retailer-supplier","Trade Efficency","Trust","All of these"], 3));
    }

    function getQuestions()public view returns(Question[] memory){
        Question[] memory questionList = new Question[](5);
        for (uint i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
          Question storage question = questions[i];
          questionList[i] = question;
        }
        return questionList;
    }

    

    function checkQuestion(uint qIndex, uint choosedAnsIndex)public view returns(bool){
        Question memory question = questions[qIndex];

        if(question.correctIndex == choosedAnsIndex){
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }



}
```

Here's the generated java wrapper class [Quiz_sol_Quiz.java](https://gist.github.com/ShoaibKakal/78171cf99dbb2a2bd0dd06afc549cc1c).

**Any help would be highly appreciated.**

Comment: is it solved ???

Comment: By the way this is the easy case :/ giving an array of Questions as parameter is the hard one

Comment: First of all don't store strings at all on your solidity smart contract. The gas usage will be huge.
Store all the content on IPFS and just store the hash on the smart contract.

Comment: For `getQuestions` you can just return `questions` without for loops or making a new array.

Comment: Can you post the error that you get when you try the code? Also maybe define the question more clearly?

Comment: the code is attached as a gist. secondly, i said web3j is n't generating code for my struct.

Comment: @GraphicalDot  this is just a complex example, thanks anyway

Comment: @RyanSea that is not the point of the question. the code is only an example

Comment: @ShoaibKhalid, I had an issue with web3j too and have write required functionality parts. The sample for structs you can find on post below.

Answer (score 0):

`Web3j` offers parent classes to implement `struct` on `Java`: `StaticStruct` and `DynamicStruct`. Below is an example of my `struct` and its implementation on `Java`.

```
struct Value {
    string _offer;
    uint256 _availableSince;
    uint256 _availabilityEnd;
    bool _isConsumed;
    uint256 _lockedUntil;
}

class Value: DynamicStruct {

    private lateinit var offer: String
    private lateinit var availableSince: BigInteger
    private lateinit var availabilityEnd: BigInteger
    private var isConsumed: Boolean = false
    private lateinit var lockedUntil: BigInteger

    constructor(
        offer: String,
        availableSince: BigInteger,
        availabilityEnd: BigInteger,
        isConsumed: Boolean,
        lockedUntil: BigInteger
    ) : super(
        Utf8String(offer), Uint256(availableSince),
        Uint256(availabilityEnd), Bool(isConsumed),
        Uint256(lockedUntil)
    ) {
        this.offer = offer
        this.availableSince = availableSince
        this.availabilityEnd = availabilityEnd
        this.isConsumed = isConsumed
        this.lockedUntil = lockedUntil
    }

    constructor(
        offer: Utf8String,
        availableSince: Uint256,
        availabilityEnd: Uint256,
        isConsumed: Bool,
        lockedUntil: Uint256
    ) : super(offer, availableSince, availabilityEnd, isConsumed, lockedUntil) {
        this.offer = offer.value
        this.availableSince = availableSince.value
        this.availabilityEnd = availabilityEnd.value
        this.isConsumed = isConsumed.value
        this.lockedUntil = lockedUntil.value
    }

}
```

Comment: Yeah thanks for your answer but my case is different. I've an array inside my struct and then that struct is itself any array. how would you deal with it?

Comment: The Problem is with Dynamic arrays of type Struct. Web3j has a bug and it doesn't generate the Struct correctly. The only possible way is a workaround without changing the contract.

Comment: Kindly try generating java code of the contract code I provided in the question, then you will realize the real problem, ig.

Comment: ```Solidity``` support arrays. When you define a ```Function``` you have to define an a ```TypeReference``` which also supports ```StaticArray``` and ```DynamicArray```. Here is a code sample https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47601052/in-web3j-how-do-you-create-a-typereference-for-array-types-discovered-at-runtim

Comment: that answer might be applicable in previous versions of web3j where we directly interact with abi files but now web3j has been much improved that we create java file to interact. So how can i do that in java file?

Comment: Do you mean this command ```web3j generate solidity -a PR_sol_ballot.abi -b PR_sol_ballot.bin -o .\Web3App\src\main\java -p com.project.contracts``` ? As I said in comment to your topic I have an issue to run this command correctly, that's why I do it manually for part of functional I need and share it with you. To move forward I have to decide between continue investing efforts in web3j to make it work properly or implement functional manually. I chosen the first, but after some threshold moved to the second.

Comment: yes, great. Can you generate the java class of above solidity code in my question?